# Validation in knockout js input fields

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I created some input fields using KnockoutJS, and now I want to validate them.

http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/43zkoszu/12/

I tried it using validation plugin but it doesn't work.
I added that plugin and used it as mentioned but didn't get the solution. When you click on "add field" a form appears; I want to make the `name` field required and `branch id` as numeric. However, when I click on "add fields" it doesn't get added until the form is validated.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your Fiddle features over 400 lines of JavaScript (not exactly a compact reproduction) but there isn't a single line of Knockout Validation in there (at least you don't use any `extend` on your observables to add validation rules). Seems like you're asking us to do your coding for you.

Comment: I tried it but my code stop working that is why i remove validation part from my code

Comment: Right now it's too broad. Don't expect anyone to provide you with a full implementation. Try to implement it yourself, and when you run into an issue, you'll be able to ask a more specific question. And usually those specific questions are already asked (and answered!) by someone before.

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing validation properly. I recommend this method

Set some settings

```
ko.validation.configure({
    insertMessages: false,
    decorateElement: true,
    errorElementClass: 'error-element',
    errorClass: 'error-element',
    errorsAsTitle: true,
    parseInputAttributes: false,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    decorateElementOnModified: true,
    decorateInputElement: true
});
```

Make inputs bind with validationElement

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" data-bind="value:name,validationElement:name">    
<input type="text" placeholder="Branch" data-bind="value:branch,validationElement:branch">
```

Extend observables

```
self.name = ko.observable().extend({required:true})
self.branch = ko.observable().extend({required:true,digit: true})
```

Now apply the rule. I prefer group

```
var data = [
    self.name,
    self.branch
]

self.Errors = ko.validation.group(data);
```

Now on add button wrap your code

```
self.Add = function(){
    if(self.Errors.length == 0){
        .
        .
        .
        //Your code here
    }else{
        self.Errors.showAllMessages()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: are you even including knockout.js?

Comment: Yes i am including it. on fiddle there is no error here is link http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/43zkoszu/11/ but still the data get submit without validation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/43zkoszu/12/ i didn't enter the word still it is passing. I put an alert if error length is zero and it is showing it if i don't enter the word in name field

Comment: you are defining self.Error outside the view model that is the problem

Comment: if you look into latest fiddle i.e http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/43zkoszu/12/ i define it inside viewmodel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542877/how-to-use-if-in-a-function-in-knockout-js can you answer this question